# Where do Excel add in manifest files install to on Mac?

Tags: excel, office-js, yeoman-generator

I have an Excel add in created using the Yeoman generator and I'm trying to find where add in manifests are installed to on the Mac file system.

I know when you sideload the add in the manifest is placed in:
`/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/wef`

But this only allows the add in to be added as a developer add in every time you open Excel.

Is there a place where I can place the add in manifest to have it stay installed in Excel not as a developer add in?

Is this the correct way to distribute an add in to users without having the add in on the AppSource store or is there another way to distribute Excel add ins via .exe/.dmgs/.pkgs?

Any information about this process would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to deploy the add-in manifest. The details are in this section of the official docs: [Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish).

Comment: None of the ways to deploy the manifest are what I asked in the original question. I'm trying to make this public to users without publishing the application to Microsoft. Is there any way to do that (.exe/.dmg/.pkg)?

Comment: There are ways to do this and they are discussed in that article. One is Centralized Deployment, and another is Network Share. Neither of them involves publishing to Microsoft, but I'm not sure what you mean by publishing to Microsoft.